# How to hide a Div by flexLayout when max-width is 768px

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I want to hide my div when max-width of the page is 768px(Tablet width) but I checked API reference of flexLayout and says that limits are 600,960,1280 and 1980 px.Is there any way I can override these pixel limits to change as 768px?fxHide.gt-sm ,hides after 960px but I need to make it 768px for example.

API reference : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API

Comment: Why not using an extra class on that div and hide it at your desire media query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS file

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
  display:none;
}
```